# How can we optimize this postgres query where we have nested select with order by limit 1

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, limit

```
SELECT tk.id AS taskid, tk.projectid, tk.NAME AS taskname, tk.code AS taskcode, (
        SELECT view1.entrydate
        FROM view1
        WHERE view1.taskid = tk.id
        ORDER BY view1.entrydate LIMIT 1
        ) AS entrystartdate, (
        SELECT view1.entrydate
        FROM view1
        WHERE view1.taskid = tk.id
        ORDER BY view1.entrydate DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS entryenddate
FROM task tk
```

Please suggest the best way to optimize this query.

This query is taking 90004 ms. The query results 2463 rows, that is the total number of rows in task table and the view used in the query doesn't take much time, it's very fast.
This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please correct me or let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: if possible give table schema + sample data

Comment: And am 100% sure that this can be optimize to get a better result, so give table schema + sample data